# Can't seem to access my Core Data from a View Controller implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to create a very simple app that manipulates an iOS core data model I've named 'Person' with the attributes: 'age', 'firstName', and 'lastName'.

However it appears that as soon as I try to GET or Query this data model, iOS appears to be returning a nil value.

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a
>   legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
>   'Person''

Here's what my view controller .m file looks like:

```
#import "bitcraft_v1ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "Person.h"

@interface bitcraft_v1ViewController ()

@end

@implementation bitcraft_v1ViewController
    @synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
    @synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
    @synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


        float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
        float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;


        NSLog(@"This is latitude: %f", latitude);
        NSLog(@"This is longitude: %f", longitude);


        Person *newPerson = [NSEntityDescription
                             insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
```

My view controller header file looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface bitcraft_v1ViewController : UIViewController

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

//- (void)saveContext;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *regionCurrentlyEntered;

@end
```

And finally I haven't touched Person.h and Person.m very much:

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * age;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastName;

@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"


@implementation Person

@dynamic age;
@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;

@end
```

I know that my view controller implementation file only declares the variable person but never actually stores a hardcoded first name, last name and age. But I can't seem to even get past this point.

Why is NSManagedObjectContext not able to find the entity Person in the Core Data? After finally declaring '`newPerson`' Will I then be able to create "John Smith 42" and store this newPerson in the core data within the `- (void)viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Where is your init code for creating the ManagedObjectContext, PersistantStoreCoordinator, etc? Usually that error comes from not having a context set up properly. It's probably that you haven't initialized the context yet. This is a good read on CoreData (although a bit overkill) as it touches on how to do a simple coreData set up + different coredata patterns for multithread/access. Look at `_setupCoreDataStack` for actual code on how to set up your context. http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: `nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter` -- once stripped of the rest of the verbiage, this should be pretty clear.  Your managedObjectContext iVar is nil.  If you don't know why that is, the relevant code would be where in the VC class you initialize the iVar, and which class owns and creates the core data stack.